# How do I get data out of a QTableView?

Tags: qt4, pyqt

I do have a `QTableView` widget with `QtGui.QTableView.SelectRows` behaviour.

1. How can I get the current selected row?
2. Can I get a specific column from that row back, and not only the id of the row?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QTableView inherits signals from QAbstractItemView. To get current selected row you have to connect your slots to one of

```
 void activated ( const QModelIndex & index )
 void clicked ( const QModelIndex & index )
 void pressed ( const QModelIndex& index )
```

**EDIT1:** QModelIndex has methods `row()` and `column()` to know exactly which cell has been clicked/selected.

```
 self.table.clicked.connect(self.clickedSlot)
 def clickedSlot(self,index):
      print "Column is " + str(index.column())
      print "Row is " + str(index.row())
```

If you are new to Qt/PyQt , You might want to see how to use signals and slots.

**EDIT2:** If you want to get indexes from the widget itself

```
self.table.selectionModel.currentIndex()
```

Comment: How do I use it? let's say i use `self.table.clicked.connect(self.download_slot)`. How can I get the `QModelIndex` var from the slot?

Comment: Is there no way to get the indexes of the table out of the widget object itself? I have a button (`QPushButton`) that I'd like to use to fire the slot.

Answer (score 0):

```
for index in sorted(self.tableView.selectionModel().selectedRows()):
    row=index.row()
    data=self.model_of_table.data(self.model_of_table.index(row, index_of_cell_in_row)
```